# Trigger save update on parent of breeze navigation property collection

Tags: breeze, asp.net-web-api

I have a breeze / webapi application which has a model that has a navigation property that is a collection of children entities. I can create new child entities and add them to the collection, I can also save these but only by then editing a value on the parent to trigger the save.

**Question is how can I manually trigger the manager to save updates to the whole object graph when I update the child collection and items?**

Thanks for any help you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch the *EntityManager.hasChangesChanged* event or the *EntityManager.entityChanged* event.  Something like this.

```
myEntityManager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function(args) {
  if (args.hasChanges) {
    myEntityManager.saveChanges();
  }
}
```

Also take a look at the api docs [here](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html)